# Insert data in new rows in UITableview using the send custom button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database, chat

I'm making an chat application using `firebasechat`. I'm using a button and trying to generate messages using both the `textfield` and `button` to send messages. I'm able to do that. However i would like to type and send the messages to show it in my `tableview` in the chat. At the moment when the user types the message, it is generates and gets created in `firebase`. This only shows in the `tableview` once i have killed and re-ran the app by pressing send. I have even updated my datasource so i don't get crashes saying the `numbers of rows isn't equal to items inserted` anymore. When i append the message to userMessages it crashes giving me this.

> 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0)

```
 var objects: [String] = []
 var userMessages = [Any]()
 var userChat:UserChat? = nil

 override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.objects = self.userChat!.iDs
 }

 @IBAction func sendButton(_ pSender: UIButton) {
        generateMessages()
    }

 private func generateMessages() {
        let userReference = UserReference(userID: AppDelegate.shared.user!.userID, fullName: AppDelegate.shared.user!.userName, status: .user)
        guard let stringText = textField.text else { return }
        let message = AppDelegate.shared.userMessages[stringText]
        self.conversationMessages.insert(AppDelegate.shared.addMessage(stringText, to: self.conversation!, sender:userReference, type: .text, date: message?.date), at: 0)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ pTableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection pSection: Int) -> Int {
        return self.userMessages.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let row = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
         let theCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reUseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
        return theCell
    }

 func objectAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> String {
        return self.objects[indexPath.row]
    }
```

Comment: Before Insert row into tableview, append message to userMessages as well, In generateMessages()

Comment: Unrelated but `self.tableView.reloadData()` in `generateMessages` is redundant. `insertRows` updates the UI. And `cellForRow` does nothing but dequeueing the cell.

Comment: @Irfan it crashes saying `'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0)`

Comment: Just a tip; don't bother with the insert/update/delete functions, just use `reloadData`. It's extremely hard to implement those functions correctly, and many seniors still choose to just use `reloadData` always and rely on UIKit to manage a smooth reload. Even much of Apple's own sample code doesn't implement it correctly.

Comment: @OscarApeland I disagree. It's quite easy to implement the methods (just keep datasource and table view in sync) and calling `reloadData` suppresses the fancy cell animation.

Comment: Not saying it's impossible, but considering OP is likely a beginner (using firebase etc) I think there's other things that's more important to learn than the sometimes-logical granular update API. `reloadData` will do the job and let him keep working on fun stuff :D My production app with 150k+ MAU use granular updates in 0 places and it's doing just fine. @vadian

Comment: @OscarApeland The error is clearly caused by using two different arrays as data source. It's not related *how* the table view UI is updated.

Comment: Yep, it was just intended as a tip as I said:) This case seems pretty solvable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is quite confusing. You have three arrays.

- In `numberOfRowsInSection` the number of `userMessages` is returned
- In `cellForRowAt` `objects` is used.
- A new message is inserted in `conversationMessages`

That's actually the error reason. Use **one** array as data source

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple arrays use single array for instance self.userMessages in numberOfRowsInSection.

use this method to update self.userMessages

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

```
    let value = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string) ?? string
```

self.userMessages.append(value)

return true

}
Now reload the tableview in   func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

Comment: both of these return a boolean

Comment: you can fetch the string from textfield and use that string to make a complete message